# Changes in Angular service property are not being reflected

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have two services and a component.

Service A:

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class AService {
        public propertyA = 'propertyA initial state';
        constructor(){}
    }
```

Service B:

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class BService{

        constructor(public _servciceA: ServiceA){}
    }
```

Component A

```
    export class AComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(public _servciceA: ServiceA, public _serviceB: ServiceB){}

        ngOnInit() {
            this._serviceB._servciceA.propertyA = 'propertyA of serviceA changed by serviceB';
            console.log(this._servciceA.propertyA) // prints 'propertyA initial state'
        }
    }
```

Both services are declared in the app.module providers section so I was expecting Both AComponent and BService were having the same instance of AService and the changes of propertyA in one, would be reflected in the other.
Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
As @benshabatnoan has said, ComponentA is in a module of a library type project. Sorry for not telling it in the given example.

- The two services are in main project.
- AService is injected in BService.
- AComponent is in another module in a library type project
- Both services are injected in the AComponent

I want the AService injected in AComponent to be the same instance as injected in BService. How can I acomplish this?

Thanks and sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can you try to remove them from module  providers?

Comment: when declaring `providedIn: 'root'` in the service, you shouldn't declare it in your module providers too. This is a duplicate registration to this service

Comment: Can you reproduce ? I have created a small example that works as intended : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ttr38

Comment: The only way I managed to reproduce this problem is when the serviceA is provided in the component's providers list

Comment: @benshabatnoam even when I declare both in module `providers`, and in decorator `providedIn` the property is updated

Comment: By the description of your question it is unclear how you're getting 2 instances of your `ServiceA` class. Maybe your `AComponent` is in another module? Another thing, maybe there is another place where you're providing `ServiceA`? You can add a breakpoint in your `ServiceA` constructor and see why it is initializing twice...

Comment: @benshabatnoan Yes, you are right. The component is in a module of a library project. How could I acomplish to have the same instance?

Comment: Thanks for the example @Florian. I have edited the question because there was some important information missing. Sorry for the confussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have quit

```
{
    providedIn: 'root'
}
```

from all services and put them in the providers section of the main module and it worked as expected.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shared since there is only one instance. Please check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afllv1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

The only difference I did is to declare the `providers` explicitly in `app.module.ts` with

```
providers: [A, B],
```

#### More details for the basic logics

Since the OP is not understanding the logic, I will elaborate further.

```
  updateA(newVal: string) { // this method to update the value within service A
    this.a.setVal(newVal);
  }

  getAVal() { // get the latest value within service A
    return this.a.getVal();
  }

  getAValFromB() { // get the latest value within service A 
    // via service B, which holds a reference to service A instance via injector
    return this.b.getValA();
  }
```

If you update the value but the value changes in both `getter` then the demonstration finishes -> they are sharing the same instance and of course you can achieve your expectation.

> Both AComponent and BService were having the same instance of AService and the changes of propertyA in one, would be reflected in the other.

For more details, please refer to the [providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers).

And [Injector hierarchy and service instances](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-hierarchy-and-service-instances), which clearly points out the rule:

> There is **only one root injector** for an app. Providing UserService at the root or AppModule level means it is registered with the root injector. There is just one UserService instance in the entire app and every class that injects UserService gets this service instance **unless you configure another provider with a child injector**.

Comment: In your demo a is not a service i.e. it does not have @Injectable() decorator. Please check.

Comment: `@Injector()` is used when this service requires another service. You can add it if you like but it changes nothing only add extra redundancy.

Comment: Perhaps you can read this post to clarify the concept: https://www.amadousall.com/angular-services-3-common-misconceptions-about-the-injectable-decorator/

Comment: @Gourishankar `@Injectable()` is only mandatory if you inject another service in your service. It's a good practice to decorate every serviec with `@Injectable`. Anyway if you declare your service with `providedIn` you're forced to use the decorator.

Comment: `The only difference I did` I would say that your code is completely different

Comment: Please check carefully and also `does your expectation really mean what you want?`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited the question because there was some important information missing.